Azure AI Search index is disabled in Azure OpenAI studio
I created some indexes and they work fine, but more recently I created a new index, "mind-star-index" and I can search over it in Azure AI search, but I cannot connect it to OpenAI because it is greyed out as shown in the image.
I could not fin a suitable answer. I built the index from scratch using a different parsing mode and selecting different search fields because the documents are JSON docs. I think it could be due to the size, because "mind-star-index" is weight over 534 Mb.

According to this documentation, as noted, the existing index must have at least one searchable field.
The same thing happened when I had 0 searchable content.

If you have searchable fields, you might need to consider the supported data formats, file types, and limitations.
Check this documentation for supported data formats and file types.
A possible reason for your case is the upload limit.
According to this documentation, the limit for total file size is:

Max size of all files per upload (Azure OpenAI on your data) -> 16 MB

So, consider all of these limits and provide your own data to query in OpenAI.

@user19  Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?
